# BizSpark deployment license hosting

Tags: sql-server, web-hosting, dedicated-hosting, bizspark

I have signed up with BizSpark and it is a great deal, especially for people like myself in perennial startup mode. As part of BizSpark you get 3 year deployment licenses for software such as Windows Server and SQL Server. Is there any dedicated hosting companies that will allow you to use these licenses without having to pay for licenses built into typically hosting accounts? For example, normally to get SQL Server Standard installed on a dedicated server at a host can cost a fair bit of extra money, but as I already have a license I shouldn't have to pay.

Comment: If anyone has signed a deal with a host I would be interested in hearing names.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions - There are many, many forums that talk about hosting and ISP services, which will certainly be able to find this information faster and more thoroughly than a group of programmers.

Comment: Yes, but let's face it. Nearly every (web) developer needs an hosting provider as some point, and frankly, I don't know and forum about hosting that even get clause to StackOverflow in terms of quality.

Comment: Great, let's apply that to every question people might ask on here.  The front page will be less than half programming related.

Comment: How is a question about hosting less programming related than this which gets plenty of up votes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549597/dealing-with-awful-estimates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I have found two hosting providers aware of BizSpark:

- http://www.peer1.com/hosting/bizspark.php
- http://www.servepath.com/bizspark/

Although, hosting providers who are afraid of displaying their prices are usually super-expensive, which probably does not fit that well with the tight-budget spirit of companies going for BizSpark.

For the record,

- http://www.crystaltech.com/ does not support BizSpark (commercial answer obtained 2009-02-19).

Feel free to edit this post, if you have links.

Answer (score 2):

Crystaltech has 4 different windows servers that will work for your BizSpark application.  They also do custom configurations.  They have been in business for 11 + years and are a Microsoft Certified Partner.  SQL and other licenses can be added a la carte but you can get a empty box.  They can be reached at 877.323.4578 option 3 ask for James.

http://crystaltech.com/dedicated-windows.aspx

Crystal Tech is currently running 3 promotions:

Pay Monthly: The RAM on the server is doubled for free.
Pay Quarterly:  Set up fee is waived ( No free RAM )
Pre pay the year: Get 3 months of service for free and the set up fee is also waived. ( No free RAM )

Comment: I have received an answer from CrystalTech. At the time (2009-02-18), they DO NOT offer any discount for BizSpark. Thus, they DO NOT support BizSpark.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the amazon cloud as Bizspark Partner and get cheaper hosting:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/windows/

http://squarecows.com/2011/10/24/new-use-your-microsoft-bizspark-licenses-on-aws/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have a few options.

1. BizSpark has a hosting company agreement, you could contact them
2. Most hosting companies with dedicated systems will sell you a basic configuration and allow you to install your own software.  (However, windows might be the only tricky one).

I personally recommend both [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com) and [HostMySite](http://www.hostmysite.com) for hosting, if you contact their sales people they will let you know what is possible.